# Controlling the SWD reset pin with another 3.3V gpio pin on mcu

Tags: debugging, arm

I have an mcu (not relevant which one) and want to control the SWD reset pin to ground. On the debug port is also connected a segger j-link. How can this savely be done with the segger probe also attached?

The segger probe use this pin as open drain. When the segger probe use the pin it drives it to LOW with the following schematic:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I connected the SWD reset pin to a free gpio and per default I define the port as IN. If now I want to reset the mcu I redefine the gpio to OUT with pinlevel LOW.
It works without any issue.